# Updating A List and Re Printing It?

Tags: python

I am trying to build a simple game but i'm having trouble updating the list and re printing it any ideas?

I am pulling some details from a txt file and putting them into a list. I print the list and this works.

I do the update using the .replace but when i re print the list it only prints the last item in the list. This has been updated correctly. How can i get it so it prints the whole list again that has been updated?

Any ideas???

Here is my code:

```
print("Can you solve the puzzle? \nBelow are some words in code form can you crack the code and figue out\nthe words?\n")
words = open ("words.txt", "r")
lines_words = words.readlines()

for line_words in lines_words:
    print (line_words)

words.close()

print("\nHere are some clues to help you!\n")

clues = open ("clues.txt", "r")
print (clues.read())

clues.close()

###

print ("\nThis is what we have so far....")

# define the function
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text


# dictionary with key:values.
reps = {'#':'A', '*':'M', '%':'N'}

txt = replace_all(line_words, reps)
print (txt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making two mistakes:

1. You *reuse* the `line_words` name in your `for` loop:

   ```
   for line_words in lines_words:
       print (line_words)
   ```

   This replaces the old value (a list) with each line *in* the list, in turn. After the last iteration that means `line_words` has been replaced by the last line.

   Use a different name for *in* the loop:

   ```
   for line in lines_words:
       print (line)
   ```
2. You'll need to use another loop to replace text in the lines:

   ```
   for line in line_words:
       txt = replace_all(line, reps)
       print (txt)
   ```

   This will obscure your words just for printing, in the iteration, and not alter the original strings contained in `line_words`.

Comment: Thank You This Has Helped SO Much! I can Continue to build my game and develope an interface using TKinter.